# Softlayer API PHP error Function ("setObjectFilter") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to use object filter to get valid device:

Below is the php code:

```
$client= SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $username, $apiKey);

    $filter = new stdClass();
    $filter->applicationDeliveryControllers = new stdClass();
    $filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem = new stdClass();
    $filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem->id = new stdClass();
    $filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem->id->operation = new stdClass();
    $filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem->id->operation = $bId;

    $client->setObjectFilter($filter);  

    try {
          $mask ='mask[id, name]';
            $client->setObjectMask($mask);
        $myInstance = $clientNetscaler->getApplicationDeliveryControllers();

    } catch(exception $ex) {

    }
```

I got the following error in my run time environment:

> There was an error querying the SoftLayer API: Function
>   ("setObjectFilter") is not a valid method for this service

The error came from line `$client->setObjectFilter($filter);`

Anybody has any idea of why there's such error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the filter is working fine. Just in case, I copied  my code. Please make sure you have PHP 5.2.3 or higher and the PHP extension for SOAP. Also try re-downloading the Softlayer PHP client https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-api-php-client and try again.

Regards

```
<?php
 require_once ('/SoapClient.class.php');
 $apiUsername = 'set me';
$apiKey = 'set me';

$accountService = Softlayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null,$apiUsername, $apiKey);
$bId = 51774239;
$filter = new stdClass();
$filter->applicationDeliveryControllers = new stdClass();
$filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem = new stdClass();
$filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem->id = new stdClass();
$filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem->id->operation = new     stdClass();
$filter->applicationDeliveryControllers->billingItem->id->operation = $bId;
$accountService->setObjectFilter($filter);  
$mask ='mask[id, name]';
$accountService->setObjectMask($mask);
try {
    $myInstance  = $accountService->getApplicationDeliveryControllers();
    print_r($myInstance);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Unable to executre the request. ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```